# Difference between first and second fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

In first fundamental theorem of calculus,it states if $A(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt$ then $A'(x)=f(x)$.But in second they say $\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt=F(b)-F(a)$,But if we put $x=b$ in the first one we get $A(b)$.Then what is the difference between these two and how do we prove $A(b)=F(b)-F(a)$?

Comment: If $f$ is continuous, then the first theorem's consequent is true, which in turn guarantees that the second theorem's consequent is also true.$$$$
If on the other hand $f$ *is not continuous*, then the first theorem is inapplicable; if $f$ is integrable **and** has a primitive (despite not being continuous), then the second theorem's consequent is true.

p.s. There exist functions that are integrable but have no primitive.

Comment: How do we prove $A(b)=F(b)-F(a)$ under valid assumptions

Comment: Check out [these](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1537821/why-does-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus-work/1537836), [previous discussions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1175571/the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus-clarification?rq=1), and [my favourite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1061683/dont-see-the-point-of-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus/1061951).

Answer (score 1):

They have different *assumptions*.

In the first part you mentioned, $f$ is assumed to be continuous. In the second part, $f$ can be assumed only Riemann integrable on the closed interval $[a,b]$. When $f$ is continuous, the second part indeed follows from the first part.

See also a comparison of the statements in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Formal_statements) article.

Comment: I didn't understand,please explain to me if A(b)=F(b)-F(a)

Comment: @AritraBarua Which part of the answer you don't understand? Please explain.

Comment: @AritraBarua: if you use $A(b)=F(b)-F(a)$, then you are using the first part, where $f$ is assumed to be continuous.